# Angular - FullCalendar dateClick not working

Tags: javascript, angular, fullcalendar, fullcalendar-4

I'm using `FullCalendar` version 4.4.0. `dayClick` event is not getting triggered in my code. My code is as follows.

calendar.component.html

```
<full-calendar
defaultView="dayGridMonth"
[plugins]="calendarPlugins"
[events]="calendarEvents"
eventColor= '#6236ff'
eventBorderColor= '#6236ff'
eventTextColor='#ffffff'
(dateClick)="handleDateClick($event)"
></full-calendar>
```

calendar.component.ts

```
handleDateClick(event){
  console.log("day", event);
}
```

When I click on the date, nothing happens. The event isn't logged into the console.

Comment: The dateClick event needs `interaction` plugin. Are you sure this plugin is loaded ?

Comment: @archelite I didn't know that. Thanks a lot. It's working now.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to add `interactionPlugin` to `calendarPlugins`

```
calendarPlugins = [dayGridPlugin, timeGrigPlugin, interactionPlugin];
```

Here is working sample I wrote for you: https://stackblitz.com/edit/fullcalendar-angular-example-ebmz5j?file=src%2Fapp%2Fapp.component.ts